# Getting push notification while Android app is in foreground mode but unable to get notification while app is not running or idle mode

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins

Please help me related to Cordova

I am using Push plugin for cordova for my Android application .

I am getting push notification while Android app is in foreground mode but unable to get notification while app is not running or idle mode .

Could you please tell me solution for same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Plugin is not supported for cordova android for background notification that's why i have used own code for push notification.

I have removed Push plugin and associated file from my cordova project.

It solves the problem of push notification with cordova android (foreground and Background both). You can use code for push plugin .

CommonUtilities.java

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

/**
 * Helper class providing methods and constants common to other classes in the
 * app.
 */
public final class CommonUtilities {

```
/**
 * Base URL of the Demo Server (such as http://my_host:8080/gcm-demo)
 */
static final String SERVER_URL = "http://www.milagro.in/wip/milagroApp/android/gcm/saveDeviceId.php";

/**
 * Google API project id registered to use GCM.
 */
static final String SENDER_ID = "593186608269";

/**
 * Tag used on log messages.
 */
static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";

/**
 * Intent used to display a message in the screen.
 */
static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION =
        "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";

/**
 * Intent's extra that contains the message to be displayed.
 */
static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

/**
 * Notifies UI to display a message.
 * <p>
 * This method is defined in the common helper because it's used both by
 * the UI and the background service.
 *
 * @param context application's context.
 * @param message message to be displayed.
 */
static void displayMessage(Context context, String message)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

boolean noti_status = false;

public GCMIntentService()
{
    super(SENDER_ID);

}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);

    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_registered));
    ServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId);
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));

    if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context))
    {
        System.out.println("registration id: "+registrationId);


       ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("registration id: "+registrationId);
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
        // This callback results from the call to unregister made on
        // ServerUtilities when the registration to the server failed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring unregister callback");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");

    //String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);

    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("notify");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);


}

@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    // log message
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
            errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

/**
 * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    String notification_message = "";


        try {
            JSONObject notiObj = new JSONObject(message);

            // String noti_type = notiObj.getString("notify_type");
            String noti_text = notiObj.getString("notify_text");
            // String noti_date = notiObj.getString("notify_date");

            notification_message = noti_text;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            System.out.println(" build version less than version 4.1");

            int icon = R.drawable.l2;
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, notification_message, when);
            String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Home_Activity.class).putExtra("message", notification_message);
            // set intent so it does not start a new activity
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, notification_message, intent);

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
        } else {*/
            System.out.println(" build version greater than version 4.1");

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.l2)
                    .setContentText(notification_message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).putExtra("message", notification_message);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

        }
```

//     }

}

public class PushNotiActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivity(new Intent(PushNotiActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
    }
}

```
public final class ServerUtilities {

private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
private static final int BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS = 2000;
private static final Random random = new Random();

/**
 * Register this account/device pair within the server.
 *
 * @return whether the registration succeeded or not.
 */
static boolean register(final Context context, final String regId)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "registering device (regId = " + regId + ")");

    String serverUrl = SERVER_URL;

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put("deviceRegID", regId);

    long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
    // Once GCM returns a registration id, we need to register it in the
    // demo server. As the server might be down, we will retry it a couple
    // times.
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempt #" + i + " to register");
        try
        {
            displayMessage(context, context.getString(R.string.server_registering, i, MAX_ATTEMPTS));

            post(serverUrl, params);

            GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_registered);
            CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // Here we are simplifying and retrying on any error; in a real
            // application, it should retry only on unrecoverable errors
            // (like HTTP error code 503).
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to register on attempt " + i, e);
            if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sleeping for " + backoff + " ms before retry");
                Thread.sleep(backoff);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // Activity finished before we complete - exit.
                Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted: abort remaining retries!");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return false;
            }
            // increase backoff exponentially
            backoff *= 2;
        }
    }
    String message = context.getString(R.string.server_register_error,
            MAX_ATTEMPTS);
    CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
    return false;
}

/**
 * Unregister this account/device pair within the server.
 */
static boolean unregister(final Context context, final String regId)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "unregistering device (regId = " + regId + ")");

    String serverUrl = SERVER_URL;

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("deviceUnRegisterID", regId);

    try
    {
        post(serverUrl, params);
        GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
        String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregistered);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);

        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // At this point the device is unregistered from GCM, but still
        // registered in the server.
        // We could try to unregister again, but it is not necessary:
        // if the server tries to send a message to the device, it will get
        // a "NotRegistered" error message and should unregister the device.
        String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregister_error,
                e.getMessage());
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);

        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Issue a POST request to the server.
 *
 * @param endpoint POST address.
 * @param params request parameters.
 *
 * @throws IOException propagated from POST.
 */
private static void post(String endpoint, Map<String, String> params)
        throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("params:  "+params+"   endpoint: "+endpoint);

    URL url;
    try
    {
        url = new URL(endpoint);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url: " + endpoint);
    }
    StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
    // constructs the POST body using the parameters
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
        bodyBuilder.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                .append(param.getValue());
        if (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            bodyBuilder.append('&');
        }
    }
    String body = bodyBuilder.toString();
    Log.v(TAG, "Posting '" + body + "' to " + url);
    byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try
    {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        // post the request
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(bytes);

        System.out.println(" server response is :   "+body);

        out.close();
        // handle the response
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (status != 200) {
          throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
        }
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
  }
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
```

{

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    prefs=getSharedPreferences("milagro",this.MODE_PRIVATE);


    loadUrl(launchUrl);


    if (getIntent().hasExtra("message")) {
        if (!getIntent().getStringExtra("message").equals("")) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title))
                    .setMessage(getIntent().getStringExtra("message"))
                    .setNeutralButton(this.getResources().getString(R.string.alert_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    }


  gcmService();

}
```

@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

```
    unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(getApplicationContext());
        this.finish();

}



private void gcmService()
{
    checkNotNull(SERVER_URL, "SERVER_URL");
    checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");
    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(MainActivity.this);

    System.out.println("*****   " + regId);

    prefs.edit().putString("deviceRegID",regId).commit();

    //APA91bFxh7qxsolGdThFwO9CXAoboPfZfPDggTpMmas2gMUibwurv_0uFmYtVTJ6xd3Cw-KD3qrjnG7GPUiLsUoOeEURM_Ryw8qtybYMG7uXo2Em8ncPH8P34IBfEgHPNvrTa_57txAk
    if (regId.equals(""))
    {
        GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), SENDER_ID);

        System.out.println("***** IF REG *****   " + regId);
    }

    else
    {
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(MainActivity.this))
        {
            System.out.println("***** ELSE REG *****   " + regId);
        }
        else
        {
            final Context context = MainActivity.this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
            {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
                {
                    boolean registered = ServerUtilities.register(context, regId);
                    // At this point all attempts to register with the app
                    // server failed, so we need to unregister the device
                    // from GCM - the app will try to register again when
                    // it is restarted. Note that GCM will send an
                    // unregistered callback upon completion, but
                    // GCMIntentService.onUnregistered() will ignore it.
                    if (!registered)
                    {
                        GCMRegistrar.unregister(getApplicationContext());
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
                {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };

            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }

    }
}




private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name)
{
    if (reference == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException(getResources().getString(R.string.error_config, name));
    }
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver =
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);

                System.out.println("new Message:  "+newMessage);

            }
        };
```

}